# OpenGL Shaders - Rotate a vertex using it's normal

Tags: java, opengl, camera, rotation, lwjgl

Given the **surfaceNormal** *(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal)* and a **gl_Vertex** how do I rotate the gl_Vertex such that it will adjust to that normal. I want to use this for billboards and general rotation.

2 Questions:

1. How would you rotate the gl_Vertex using the surfaceNormal *(In the .vert shader)*?
2. Should the rotation be done on the GPU (in the shader) or on the CPU? *(Please adjust question **#1** according to this question given 2 Vector3fs, one for the rotation (normal) the other for the vertex position if it should be done on the CPU)*

Thanks!

Comment: YOur question doesn't make sense. What is "rotate the gl_Vertex such that it will adjust to that normal" supposed to mean? A direction doesn't describe a rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of cases, the rotation should be done on the CPU, by the way of the model matrix (or directly world matrix).

Even if the CPU is slower than the GPU, keep in mind a vertex shader will have been executed for each vertex, whereas a model matrix linked to a mesh, so a lot of vertices, shall be calculated only once per frame if your mesh is dynamic, and only once of your entire program if your mesh won't move.